# My lsp says there are non-default libraries or their files (only for not default libraries (numpy, boost, matplotlib etc))

Tags: neovim, pyright, clangd, neovim-plugin

it says:

It doesn't see libraries but it still provides suggestions

`‘boost/version.hpp’ file not found`
`Cannot filnd implementation or library stub for module named “numpy”`
`Cannot filnd implementation or library stub for module named “matplot”`
`Cannot filnd implementation or library stub for module named “scipy.optimize”`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4LLf.png):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEKKs.png)

I use codelldb, clangs, pyright, mypy
libraries are installed and programs work.

I use nevoid (NvChad) this is my lspconfig.lua that use clangs and pyright:

```
local M = {}
local conf = require("nvconfig").ui.lsp
local base = require('nvchad.configs.lspconfig')
local on_attach = base.on_attach
local capabilities = base.capabilities
local on_init = base.on_init

local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
local util = require "lspconfig/util"

lspconfig.clangd.setup {
  on_init = on_init,
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    client.server_capabilities.signatureHelpProvider = false
    on_attach(client, bufnr)
  end,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}

lspconfig.pyright.setup({
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  filetypes = {"python"},
})

lspconfig.gopls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  cmd = {"gopls"},
  filetypes = { "go", "gomod", "gowork", "gotmpl" },
  root_dir = util.root_pattern("go.work", "go.mod", ".git"),
  settings = {
    gopls = {
      completeUnimported = true,
      usePlaceholders = true,
      analyses = {
        unusedparams = true,
      },
    },
  },
}

local servers = {"tsserver", "tailwindcss", "eslint"}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    on_init = on_init,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

local function organize_imports()
  local params = {
    command = "_typescript.organizeImports",
    arguments = {vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)},
  }
  vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(params)
end

lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  init_options = {
    preferences = {
      disableSuggestions = true,
    }
  },
  commands = {
    OrganizeImports = {
      organize_imports,
      description = "Organize Imports",
    }
  }
}

M.on_init = function(client, _)
  if not conf.semantic_tokens and client.supports_method "textDocument/semanticTokens" then
    client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil
  end
end

return M
```

Ive updated everything,

tried to solve problem with cpp

```
M.on_init = function(client, _)
    if not conf.semantic_tokens and client.supports_method("textDocument/semanticTokens") then
        client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil
    end

    -- Add your include paths and compile flags here
    client.config.settings.clangd = {
        compileFlags = {
            "/usr/local/Cellar/", // where boost is located
        }
    }
end
```